# Execute SQL query from Rails when connecting to SQL Server 2005 through activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, activerecord

So I'm connecting to SQL Server 2005 from my Rails app via the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.

I'm able to execute stored procs by doing

```
Mymodel.execute_procedure("thisProcedure", param1, param2)
```

But I have a stored proc that has a SQL INOUT variable that I'm having trouble with. I execute it, and I'm not seeing that variable returned.

So now I'm trying to just execute some raw sql, such as

```
declare @thisVar int
EXEC thatProcedure 1, 1, @thisVar = @thisVar output
print @thisVar
```

When I do

```
sql = "declare @thisVar int
EXEC thatProcedure 1, 1, @thisVar = @thisVar output
print @thisVar"

foo = Mymodel.connection.execute(sql)
```

I'm not getting any errors and everything looks successful. I get back foo that has a class of DBI::StatementHandle. How do I actually see the response from the SQL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a while since I waded into DBI, we left stored procedures in favor of ORMs.  To get the data from the StatementHandle object, you need to issue a fetch all.  That should have all of your return values/output parameters as well as result set if applicable as an array.  This was dbi version .4.1 which I believe is the last version to work with the sqlserver adapter.

```
sql = "declare @thisVar int
EXEC thatProcedure 1, 1, @thisVar = @thisVar output
print @thisVar"

foo = Mymodel.connection.execute(sql)

result_array = foo.fetch_all
```

and then you can loop through the resulting array.

Here is the DBI documentation http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html

You might want to also look at the new activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.  It eliminates DBI entirely, not sure how it handles SPs though.

http://github.com/rails-sqlserver/2000-2005-adapter

My advice, for what it is worth, mixing ORMs and stored procedures is extremely difficult because you are splitting the business logic between two layers and it gets increasingly difficult to manage.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Where does sth get defined?

I tried foo.fetch_all and I get "DBI::InterfaceError: Statement was already closed!"

Comment: doh, sorry about that.  Was looking at 2 year old code when I wrote that, sth was hiding away in there - sth=foo as you suspected.  I confess that I bypassed AR when I had to deal with the stored procedures specifically for this reason, I was also still 'getting acquainted' with rails.  Another option might be to have the stored procedure return the parameters as a result set `SELECT @output_parameter as somevalue`.  Then at least you are dealing with something AR can handle.